# How does one `git log` tagged commits only?

Tags: git

I'd like to `git log` all the tagged commits on the master branch (and none of the untagged commits). Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The secret trick to this is to realize that `git log` uses the same rules as `git rev-list`.  The latter command has a `--tags` flag to look at tags.  So, as with the other answers so far, if you're willing to look at *all* tagged commits, this single command will do it:

```
git log --no-walk --tags
```

(The `--no-walk` prevents this from starting with tags and finding all their parent commits, and the parents' parents, and so on.)

But you asked for "tagged commits on the master branch", which I assume means (in technical terms)  "commits that are both pointed to by tags *and* reachable via the `master` branch".  This is substantially harder (`git rev-list` can do set union via `--stdin --no-walk`, but seems to have no way to do set intersection).  Here are several methods of finding the right commit-IDs, with various drawbacks:

1. First make two file lists: "all tagged commits" and "all commits reachable from master":

   ```
   git rev-list --tags --no-walk > /tmp/all-tags
   git rev-list master > /tmp/all-master
   ```

   Now just print lines that appear only in both files.  The [`comm` utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm) can do this.  It's documented to expect the files to be sorted, but in all implementations I have seen, the files merely need to be in the *same* order, as it were, so this works without pre-sorting:

   ```
   comm -12 /tmp/all-tags /tmp/all-master
   ```

   Drawbacks: needs two temporary files (unless you use the special `bash` syntax that uses `/dev/fd`); might not work without sorting; requires `comm`.
2. Same idea as before, but use `uniq -d` to produce the list.  This really *does* require sorting, but you can eliminate the temporary files using a pipe:

   ```
   (git rev-list --tags --no-walk; git rev-list master) | sort | uniq -d
   ```

   Drawback: requires sorting.  The commits come out in some strange order, not the order you would normally see with `git log`.
3. Write your own utility that basically does what the `comm` method would do, but invokes `git rev-list` itself (perhaps a script that creates temp files using `mktemp` to make unique names).

   Drawback: requires a lot more work. :-)

In all cases, once you have the list of commit-IDs, you just need to pass them to `git log --no-walk`, e.g.:

```
git log --no-walk $(comm -12 /tmp/all-tags /tmp/all-master)
```

Comment: Great answer! I did try `--tags`, but not in conjunction with `--no-walk`. The simple command actually gets me 95% of the way there (though I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer).

Answer (score 2):

There are probably lots of ways of going about this, but here's one that I think will do what you want:

```
git tag | 
xargs -iCID git --no-pager log -1  CID
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, but along the same lines:

```
git tag | xargs git show --quiet
```

Comment: using it with `--oneline` option is what I was looking for. Thks

Answer (score 2):

A lot has happened in Git since 2014; modern users may find this command useful for this purpose:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --tags --pretty='tformat:%C(auto)%h %as%d %s'
```

And if you want to include other decorations (like branches), just remove `--tags`:

```
git log --simplify-by-decoration --pretty='tformat:%C(auto)%h %as%d %s'
```

Alternatively, you may find this useful:

```
git tag -l --format='%(tag) %(taggerdate:short) %(objectname:short) %(subject)'
```