# Get a list of all tags between two commits

Tags: git, git-tag

I have two commit hashes and want to list all the tags that begin with `phinx-` between these two commit hashes. How can I do it?

**Edit:**

This is what I have come up with. Is there a better solution

```
git log --pretty=format:'%D' 35164f33..49085fbe | grep -o 'tag: phinx-[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the [comm](http://ss64.com/bash/comm.html) command, check out this solution

```
comm -23 <(git tag -l phinx-* --contains <sha1 start>) <(git tag -l phinx-* --contains <sha1 end>)
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Thank you.

Comment: I like this one because the pattern is matched only against the tag name and only the tag name is returned, not the whole log line

Comment: Using `comm` is what I suggested in the answer [VonC linked in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36787860/1256452).  It should work fine, but see the caveat there mentioning the documentation's claim that comm inputs should be sorted.  (Fortunately `git tag -l` defaults to sorting as well!)

Answer (score 2):

A quick hack could be:

```
git log --oneline --decorate <sha1>..<sha1>|grep "tag:"| grep "phinx-"
```

An actual solution [might be more complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21570658/6309) and involve [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list).

Comment: Thank you @VonC. The quick solution was my first thought too.